# winscp file upload duplicate files are uploaded with name of file plus DD_MM_YY_HH_mm_SS

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, winscp

I am using following code to upload the file to sftp

```
using (Session session = new Session())
                {
                    
                    session.Open(sessionOptions);

                    using var s = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(content ?? ""));
                    TransferOptions o = new TransferOptions { OverwriteMode= OverwriteMode.Overwrite };
                    session.PutFile(s, remoteFilePath, o);

                    session.Close();
                    result = true;
                }
```

sometime for no reason i see duplicate file with suffix  as per time (DD_MM_YY_HH_mm_ss) uploaded

any idea what could be the problem

Comment: We need more information. Session log file showing the duplicate file upload at the very least. What does it mean "duplicate file uploaded" anyway? You cannot have two fails with the same name.

Comment: problem is resolved. i have shared the answer already

Answer (score 1):

I would try again the upload process, using the [official example](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library#example)

```cs
using System;
using WinSCP;
 
class Example
{
    public static int Main()
    {
        try
        {
            // Setup session options
            SessionOptions sessionOptions = new SessionOptions
            {
                Protocol = Protocol.Sftp,
                HostName = "example.com",
                UserName = "user",
                Password = "mypassword",
                SshHostKeyFingerprint = "ssh-rsa 2048 xxxxxxxxxxx..."
            };
 
            using (Session session = new Session())
            {
                // Connect
                session.Open(sessionOptions);
 
                // Upload files
                TransferOptions transferOptions = new TransferOptions();
                transferOptions.TransferMode = TransferMode.Binary;
 
                TransferOperationResult transferResult;
                transferResult =
                    session.PutFiles(@"d:\toupload\*", "/home/user/", false, transferOptions);
 
                // Throw on any error
                transferResult.Check();
 
                // Print results
                foreach (TransferEventArgs transfer in transferResult.Transfers)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Upload of {0} succeeded", transfer.FileName);
                }
            }
 
            return 0;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", e);
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

That way, you can:

- confirm the issue persists
- **check for errors**
- inspect the [`TransferOperationResult`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_transferoperationresult)

Double-check for any [formatting timestamp option in Batch File](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/script_formatting_timestamp_batch_file), i.e. any `%TIMESTAMP%` environment variable set.

Answer (score 0):

what i did is instead of separate one by one call i done thing in a loop and instead of opening session each time i open it when it is not opened

```
using (Session session = new Session())
                {
                    if (!session.Opened)
                    {
                        session.Open(sessionOptions);
                    }

                    foreach (var item in newContents)
                    {

                        try
                        {
                            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_config.DefaultPath))
                            {
                                item.SftpFileName = _config.DefaultPath + item.SftpFileName;
                            }

                            using var s = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(item.Content ?? ""));

                            session.PutFile(s, item.SftpFileName, o);

                            item.IsSuccess= true;
                        }
                        catch (Exception exception)
                        {
                            _logger.LogError(exception, $"Failed in uploading file to using winscp [{item.SftpFileName}]");
                        }
                    }
                    session.Close();
                }
```

Comment: That should work indeed. Upvoted.

Comment: @VonC you have any suggestion for any more improvement then please share